# Error when trying to access a dynamic property of a PFUser subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfuser

I'm using [Parse.com](https://parse.com/) and I have a `PFUser` subclass called `NPUser`.

Here's the code:

**NPUser.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface NPUser : PFUser <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic) NSString *facebookId;

- (NSURL *)profileImageURL;

@end
```

**NPUser.m**

```
#import "NPUser.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation NPUser

@dynamic facebookId;

+ (void)load {
    [self registerSubclass];
}

- (NSURL *)profileImageURL {
    // -- This is where things blow up -- 
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", self.facebookId];
    return [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
}

@end
```

When I call `profileImageURL` something weird happens, it seems like execution just aborts but the app doesn't freeze. I put a breakpoint on the first line and narrowed it down to `self.facebookId` failing.

When I call `self.facebookId` or `self[@"facebookId"]` or `[self objectForKey:@"facebookId"]` (which I believe are all the same thing) I get this error:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-3)..
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

I've read [this question on Parse about subclassing PFUser](https://www.parse.com/questions/subclass-pfuser) but I didn't find anything in there that could help me. I also read the [docs on subclassing PFObject](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses-defining/iOS) and followed whatever was said there.

The thing is all the functionality works otherwise (my `NPUser` class seems to get called properly and all its properties get set properly). The `facebookId` property is also saved properly when I inspect the data dashboard on Parse.com.

I should mention that when I inspect the called user object it says it's a `PFUser` not a `NPUser` but the `profileImageURL` method (which is only defined in `NPUser`) does get called.

I'm puzzled by this. Any thoughts or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I slept on it and found the problem, it was a silly oversight on my part.

Basically in this case I wasn't accessing the user object directly. Instead, it was a pointer association to another object I had. So the problem was I wasn't calling:

```
[query includeKey:@"user"];
```

when querying that other object so it wasn't actually including the full object. It was sneaky because there was an actual object there and its methods were being called but its dynamic properties weren't implemented (from what I could tell).

Hopefully this helps someone else out in the future.

Comment: Definitely helped me. in my case, it just stopped working out of nowhere after several days of dev/testing. I had to include a key from an array of objects `query.includeKey("listOfThings.object")`. I've been having all kinds of crazy/scary stuff like this happen w/ the Parse SDK.